Chrome extension : Inject User desired CSS Before loading
I'm making a Chrome extension, in this extension I let the user to choose to hide some elements as a top bar for example.
I'm using chrome.storage to store the settings chosen by the user and inject the CSS in my .js file at loading.
The thing is js is injected after the dom loaded, so there is a visual clipping.
I put this into manifest.json
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.goodreads.com/*"],
        "css": ["assets/css/enhancer.css"],
        "js": ["assets/js/enhancer.js"],
        "runAt": "document_start"
    }
  ]

I tried a simple css injection without looking at chrome.storage :
let cssStyle = '.siteHeader__topFullImageContainer {display : none !important; }';
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssStyle));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

But it's still too slow, top bar appears and disappear.
So I was wondering, is there a possibility to store a CSS file filled by user settings ?
=> User choose something, I format it into a CSS file and this CSS file is called in my manifest.json, so technically loaded with DOM
Thanks for reading me, have a great day !

Typo: runAt should be run_at.

It worked @woxxom, thanks a lot !

Is it still possible to store somewhere faster than chome.storage ?

Yes, but that depends on what configuration contains and how it affects the injected CSS. Please describe it in the question or in a comment.

I used localStorage, it seems to be the best way to avoid asynchronous methode chrome.storage and inject faster the CSS
